Identify this (French) animated series, produced in the 80s and featuring a very futuristic setting
When I was a kid I remember watching this French animated show on TV (though there's a slight chance I might be wrong about the country of origin), probably produced in the 80s.
It was about these people who lived in this sci-fi world, they were coloured in blue and had patterns drawn on them (the entire world as I recall was coloured various shades of blue). They would travel on these hoverboard/surfboard-like devices.
The entire thing had a futuristic and a slightly surreal feel. I do recall the protagonist being a boy and there also being a girl and I think there was a baddie who was a giant metal sphere with a face (maybe it was a computer?).
Not much to go on, sorry. That's all I can remember.

I found it, I thought it was a fairly popular cartoon but it seems I was wrong (according to a poster on tvtropes, it's actually pretty obscure):
It's called "Bleu, l'enfant de la Terre", with a video of the opening here.

Although it is your own answer, if you mark it as ‘Accepted’ then you'll go towards letting other readers know that you discovered the serial and do not need additional answers — that part helps the reviewers of new answers.

I cannot comment so I'm going to have to guess here. Being a 90's kid, I think what you mean is ReBoot : http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108903/
I remember this TV show was fascinating, I just can't remember anything other than a joker appearance (clown like baddy) and some sort of races in space. Let me know if that's the right answer :P

No, sadly, it's not that, it was definitely not CGI, it used traditional animation (and it had a very pronounced 80s vibe). But I do recall this one though, primarily the main character.

Nice to see you found it ! I never saw that even if I was born late 80's and watched french tv !!! It looks weird haha

I know! it was so difficult to find, at one point I even thought "Had I hallucinated all of this?" but no, it's for real.
